# Appending to empty df in for loop R

Tags: r

I have looked at similar answers but none of them quite answer my task.

I have found a very messy answer to my question but would like advice as to whether there is a simpler way.

I have a file list of many tables that I want to import into R and append columns to an empty df.
The rownames or column 1 will be the same for each imported table/df but the number of columns (sample_ids) will change.

At the moment I create a vector outside the loop and name it with the row names that I know won't change. Then I loop through the dfs and do a left_join using the same col name

Something like this:

```
final_df<-c(the row names that I want to extract)
names(final_df) <- "Sample_ID"

for (i in 1:length(files)){
my_df<-read_tsv(files[i])
# get the table specific sample names
my_sn <- my_df[15,-c(1:3)]

# get the rows I want to extract
my_df<-filter(row names I want to extract)
names(my_df)<-c("Sample_ID", my_sn)

final_df<-left_join(final_df, my_df, by="Sample_ID")

}
```

I'm thinking there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: use `data.table::rbindlist`  E.g. `rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), use.names=T, fill=T)`

Comment: Hi @dww, I think I'm after something more of a cbindlist (which I tried but couldn't get to work)